# T4 generation issues

Tags: c#, sql, t4

I'm trying to learn some C# and coming from a data background. Now I want to generate some SQL code based on a database. I'm working with the examples from https://damieng.com/blog/2009/11/06/multiple-outputs-from-t4-made-easy-revisited. When I download the solution from Github (https://github.com/DanielGasson/t4-examples) it works.

But I'm having some issues with this. I hope that somebody can help me a little because that I've tried many things and I get frustrated that this doesn't work.... So maybe somebody can get me back on track with some hints:

My issues:

**Problem 1 - adding SQL connection**
I want to add some SQL to retieve some data that must be generated but now I have a C# project which gives problems when I try to add some SQL connection code like:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
string selectQueryTables = "select * from [config].[TargetTables]"; 
SqlDataAdapter commandTables = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryTables,conn);
```

This leads to this error:
The type or namespace name 'SqlConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) T4CustomFileGeneration

I tried to add NuGet System.Data.SqlClient but that didn't solve anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
After the tip off @Zer0 I've this:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text"#>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating"#>
<#@ output extension="/" #>
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="True"#>
<#@ include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
using System.Data.SqlClient;

<#
    var manager = new Manager(Host, GenerationEnvironment, true, "T4CustomFileGeneration")
    {
        OutputPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile),
    };
#>

<#
    string connectionString = ""; 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
....
```

So that's both solutions but the errors are still there:

[image: error]

Full code:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE"#>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text"#>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating"#>
<#@ output extension="/" #>
<#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="True"#>
<#@ include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data"#>

<#
    var manager = new Manager(Host, GenerationEnvironment, true, "T4CustomFileGeneration")
    {
        OutputPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile),
    };
#>

<#
    string connectionString = ""; 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
    string selectQueryTables = "select * from [config].[Tables]"; 
    SqlDataAdapter commandTables = new SqlDataAdapter(selectQueryTables,conn); 

    DataSet TablestoGenerate = new DataSet();
    commandTables.Fill(TablestoGenerate, "Tables");
    var manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this);
#>

<# manager.StartBlock("FooStoredProc.sql", "Stored Procedures"); #>
CREATE PROC FOO ...
<# manager.EndBlock(); #>

<# manager.Process(); #>
```

Comment: For your first issue, add `using System.Data.SqlClient;` or define `conn` explicitly like this `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = ...`.  Also please post only one specific question at a time.

Comment: Ok @Zer0. I'll continu with where you replied to.

I've tried this:


<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
.....
<#@ include file="Manager.ttinclude"#>
using System.Data.SqlClient;

And I've tried:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

But in both cases I get:

The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) + also for SqlConnection, SqlDataAdapter and DataSet.

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your question with more information.  Easier for me to read.  Thanks.

Comment: I've done that @Zer0.

Comment: Oh, that's just a syntax issue.  Try `<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"#>`.  I'd also do `<#@ import namespace="System.Data"#>`.  I'm not sure what IDE you're using, but Visual Studio should suggest namespaces if it can easily identify the type, in most cases.

Comment: I use Visual Studio, but now I've added 2 lines:

<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"#>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data"#>

Directly after <#@ include file="Manager.ttinclude"#> but the error still exists @Zer0.

Comment: Can you post an MRE?  Full, but minimal amount of, example code we can run that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I don't know what an MRE is? Even couldn't find it on Google. I've posted the full code that I have in GenerateFiles.tt, which is in my solution together with Manager.ttinclude. Is this what you where looking for @Zer0?

Comment: Apologies I [should have linked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to information on an MRE.  Basically, the smallest amount of code we can copy and run on our end that reproduces the issue.  See if you can make this error happen on a new tiny test project.

Comment: Note that T4 is a dead-end technology, it won't even run in .Net Core and 5+. The modern way to do something like this is with source generators.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the T4 source:

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
```

For example, you can use the following link
[enter link description here](https://terrybrown.me/posts/old/using-t4-to-generate-enums-from-database-lookup-tables/)